# using-declaration may not name namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17, using

If I have a file like this, everything works as expected:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   std::filesystem::path o = "C:\\Windows\\write.exe";
   auto s = o.parent_path();
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

However I would like to use a line like this if possible:

```
filesystem::path o = "C:\\Windows\\write.exe";
```

I tried this but I get an error:

```
// using-declaration may not name namespace 'std::filesystem'
using std::filesystem;
```

and error with this too:

```
using namespace std::filesystem;
// error: 'filesystem' has not been declared
filesystem::path o = "C:\\Windows\\write.exe";
```

Is it possible to do what I am attempting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a namespace alias like

```
namespace filesystem = std::filesystem;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        int x;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    namespace B = A::B;
    
    B::x = 10;
    
    std::cout << B::x << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
10
```

Comment: Such a precise and simple answer. Nice!